# Django Update view creates new object while also updating

Tags: django

I'm working on a test application in Django and have run in to an issue I've been unable to solve.

I have two models, Farm and Product which have a One to Many relationship. When creating a Farm you can add multiple images which gets added as individual products with the Farm as the foreign key.

As I was working on being able to update the name of the farm I also wanted to add the ability to add more products on the same page. So I wrote a post function that is similiar to the one I used for creating the farm. However when I submit the update it doesn't only update and add the new products, it also creates a new farm object with the same name.

I think I have to get the correct instance for this to work but I don't have enough experience with Django to know where I need to implement those changes. (I might also have to change from the UpdateView to something else, if so please let me know!)

Here is my UpdateView:

```
    class FarmUpdateView(UpdateView):
        model = Farm
        fields = ['title']

        def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            farm = self.get_object()
            form_class = self.get_form_class()
            form = self.get_form(form_class)
            files = request.FILES.getlist('images')
            if form.is_valid():
                title = form.cleaned_data['title']
                updateFarm = farm
                updateFarm.title = title
                updateFarm.save()
                farm_id = updateFarm
                for f in files:
                    Product.objects.create(image=f, farm=farm_id)
                return self.form_valid(form)
            else:
                return self.form_invalid(form)
```

And here is my template:

```
        <form method="post" class="farm-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}
            <label for="farm-image">Images</label>
            <input type="file" name="images" class="form-control-file" id="farm-image" multiple>
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: What if you write `self.object = farm = self.get_object()`? Note that the `get_form` uses `self.object`.

Comment: That did it!  Thank you so much I've been stuck with this issue all day. (Can you mark comments as the answer to the question?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason this fails is because you did not set `self.object` before making a form with `get_form`. As we can see in the [source code of **`get_form_kwargs`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/views/generic/edit.py#L103-L108), it will pass `self.object` as instance, if it exists:

> ```
>     def get_form_kwargs(self):
>         """Return the keyword arguments for instantiating the form."""
>         kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
>         if hasattr(self, 'object'):
>             kwargs.update({'instance': self.object})
>         return kwargs
> ```

So that means your `self.get_form` will construct a form, without an instance, and thus *create* a record.

You furthermore also do too much manual work yourself. Django's modelforms actually can remove a lot of boilerplate code. You can implement the creation of the `Product`s in the `form_valid` method, and let Django do most of the work for you:

```
class FarmUpdateView(UpdateView):
        model = Farm
        fields = ['title']

        def form_valid(self, form):
            farm = form.instance
            products = [
                Product(image=f, farm_id=farm) for f in request.FILES.getlist('images')
            ]
            Product.objects.bulk_create(products)
            super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Willem. I was struggling with the same issue as the OP. I suppose it's because [Django documentation for multiple file upload](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/file-uploads/) suggests to override post method.

When I tried to use your code, I had to slightly adjust it : adding a return statement before super() and also adding "self." before request.FILES.